# Are there any solutions to the fact that Testcafe doesn't work on MacOS images with SIP enabled?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Currently, we use Github Actions to run our Testcafe suites, but the problem is running Safari tests on the `macos-latest` image, which is 10.15 Catalina, gives the following error:

`UnableToAccessScreenRecordingAPIError: The find-window process cannot access the Screen Recording API.`

This is because MacOS images don't come with that permission granted by default. Apparently you can't handle this programmatically, and there's a feature called SIP that is turned on in 10.15 Catalina that stops you from getting around it. This is discussed [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5352).

Since we're relying on Github to provide images, they've not been able to provide us with a non-SIP image as discussed [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/650). The workarounds provided there have been of no help.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned, TestCafe doesn't capture screenshots and resize them because of SIP enabled on machines with MacOS. However, it is possible to use the remote mode since the platform specific functionality is disabled by default. You can execute these steps:

```
testcafe remote test.js --hostname ${HOSTNAME} --ports ${PORT1},${PORT2} &
pid=$!
open -a Safari http://${HOSTNAME}:${PORT1}/browser/connect
wait $pid
```

Comment: Thanks, looking into this - I'm not sure what I should be specifying as the host here - can I direct the container with Testcafe to point to itself (i.e. `localhost`)? Otherwise there is no other remote target to connect to - I am not doing anything on my local machine, this is all self contained in a CI image...

Comment: Yes, `localhost` should be used as a hostname because everything will be performed in the CI agent. The idea is to run TestCafe tests in your CI in remote mode and to navigate a browser to the remote connection URL, which is known in advance. I created a [repo](https://github.com/wentwrong/test-macos-latest) to demonstrate this idea.

Comment: This still provokes a request for screen recording permissions on my system, even with --disable-screenshots